# Reading a .txt file and excluding certain elements

Tags: java

In my journey to complete this program I've run into a little hitch with one of my methods. The method I am writing reads a certain .txt file and creates a HashMap and sets every word found as a Key and the amount of time it appears is its Value. I have managed to figure this out for another method, but this time, the .txt file the method is reading is in a weird format. Specifically:

```
more 2
morning's 1
most 3
mostly 1
mythology. 1
native 1
nearly 2
northern 1
occupying 1
of 29
off 1
```

And so on. 
Right now, the method is returning only one line in the file.

Here is my code for the method:

```
  public static HashMap<String,Integer> readVocabulary(String fileName) {
   // Declare the HashMap to be returned
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap();
    String toRead = fileName;

     try {
      FileReader reader = new FileReader(toRead);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);

      // The BufferedReader reads the lines      
      String line = br.readLine();


      // Split the line into a String array to loop through
      String[] words = line.split(" ");

      // for loop goes through every word
      for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        // Case if the HashMap already contains the key.
        // If so, just increments the value.        
        if (wordCount.containsKey(words[i])) { 
          int n = wordCount.get(words[i]);    
          wordCount.put(words[i], ++n);
        }
        // Otherwise, puts the word into the HashMap
        else {
          wordCount.put(words[i], 1);
        }
      }
      br.close();
    }
    // Catching the file not found error
    // and any other errors
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
      System.err.println("File not found.");
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.print(e);
    }

    return wordCount;
  }
```

The issue is that I'm not sure how to get the method to ignore the 2's and 1's and 29's of the .txt file. I attempted making an 'else if' statement to catch all of these cases but there are too many. Is there a way for me to catch all the ints from say, 1-100, and exlude them from being Keys in the HashMap? I've searched online but have turned up something.

Thank you for any help you can give!

Comment: You could use a regex if. So if the words matches the regex then dont add it. Youre regex would be something like ^(\d*)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just doing `wordCount.put(words[0],1)` into `wordcount` for every line, after you've done the split.  If the pattern is always "word number", you only need the first item from the split array.

---

**Update after some back and forth**

```
public static HashMap<String,Integer> readVocabulary(String toRead)
{ 
    // Declare the HashMap to be returned 
    HashMap<String, Integer> wordCount = new HashMap<String, Integer>(); 

    String line = null;
    String[] words = null;
    int lineNumber = 0;
    FileReader reader = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try { 
        reader = new FileReader(toRead); 
        br = new BufferedReader(reader); 

        // Split the line into a String array to loop through 
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            lineNumber++;
            words = line.split(" "); 
            if (words.length == 2) {

                if (wordCount.containsKey(words[0]))
                { 
                    int n = wordCount.get(words[0]); 
                    wordCount.put(words[0], ++n); 
                } 
                // Otherwise, puts the word into the HashMap 
                else
                {  
                    boolean word2IsInteger = true;
                    try  
                    {  
                        Integer.parseInt(words[1]);
                    } 
                    catch(NumberFormatException nfe)  
                    {  
                        word2IsInteger = false;  
                    }
                    if (word2IsInteger) {
                        wordCount.put(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1])); 
                    }
                } 
            }
        } 
        br.close();
        br = null;
        reader.close();
        reader = null;
    } 
    // Catching the file not found error 
    // and any other errors 
    catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) { 
        System.err.println("File not found."); 
    } 
    catch (Exception e) { 
        System.err.print(e); 
    } 

    return wordCount; 
}
```

Comment: So you're saying that the only items actually going into my words[] array is one line, so since the first element will always be a word, only words will be put in the HashMap? How would I change my code to make it go through every line and put each line into the words[] array with two elements and do the above?

Comment: I updated with sample code.  So this example reads ever line until there are none (readLine() == null).  And assuming the patter is regular (always one word and one number on the line), it simply takes the first element `[0]` of the split and does the lookup and/or insertion logic with the HashMap.

Comment: I actually misread the instructions. I need to save the word as a Key and the Value as the number associated with it in the line. How would I go about that? I'm sorry for the confusion!

Comment: @KommanderKitten, I updated to `wordCount.put(words[0], words[1]);` in the else.  Not sure what it should do if the word already exists, though (the if part).  I.e. if the word already exists, should it increment by one?  I left it doing that for now.

Comment: in               wordCount.put(words[0], words[1]); I am getting an error. I can't save a string as an int. Do you know of a work-around?

Comment: I changed the insertion to `wordCount.put(words[0], Integer.parseInt(words[1]));`

Comment: NullPointerException.... been combing through my code for a reason. Can't find it. Any ideas? I appreciate all your help!

Comment: What line is the NullPointerException?

Comment: It doesn't say. It's in the catch. So all it prints is what it is. Is there a way of finding out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75040/discussion-between-dwright-and-kommander-kitten).

Answer (score 1):

To check if a String contains a only digits use String´s matches() method, e.g.

```
if (!words[i].matches("^\\d+$")){
  // NOT a String containing only digits
}
```

This wont require checking exceptions and it doesnt matter if the number wouldnt fit inside an Integer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: Ignore numbers separated by whitespace

Use Integer.parseInt() or Double.parseInt() and catch the exception.

```
// for loop goes through every word
  for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    try {
       int wordAsInt = Integer.parseInt(words[i]);
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
       // Case if the HashMap already contains the key.
       // If so, just increments the value. 
       if (wordCount.containsKey(words[i])) { 
          int n = wordCount.get(words[i]);    
          wordCount.put(words[i], ++n);
       } 
       // Otherwise, puts the word into the HashMap
       else {
          wordCount.put(words[i], 1);
       }
    }
  }
```

There is a `Double.parseDouble(String)` method, which you could use in place of `Integer.parseInt(String)` above if you wanted to eliminate all numbers, not just integers.

#### Option 2: Ignore numbers everywhere

Another option is to parse your input one character at a time and ignore any character that isn't a letter. When you scan whitespace, then you could add the word generated by the characters just scanned in to your HashMap. Unlike the methods mentioned above, scanning by character would allow you to ignore numbers even if they appear immediately next to other characters.